# Does deploying a custom object delete any new fields only added in production?

Tags: deployment, change-set

When i deploy a custom object from the sandbox to production and someone has added a new custom field but they only added it to production.  Will the deploy erase that field or ignore it.

Feels like it would ignore it because what you are really deploying from the sandbox is the fields but i wanted to see what others had experienced?

Comment: Deploy should never erase any new fields, however it will try to update any fields if the API names from deploy matches the API names of the fields in you're Production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you tagged your OP with `change-set`, I'm going to assume that is what you are using.

If you deploy an object via ChangeSets - it won't deploy any fields (!). Nor will it deploy the object's tab, listviews, custom buttons, page layouts, or recordtypes, if any. Deploying an object deals with the object name, plural, etc. but not its components.

You need to deploy individual Custom Fields as well in the changeset. These fields will overwrite their equivalent in PROD but will leave untouched any PROD fields not mentioned in the changeset.

Comment: Hmm right, do you know what happens when you deploy an object with mavensmate?

Comment: I'm not a MM user but in Eclipse , when you deploy an object it deploys the custom fields  as well.

Comment: Right I think it's the same, but that wouldn't delete any fell that we're added in production either right?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: All metadata tools work the same. Nothing is deleted without a "destructive change" request, which is always explicit. It's hard to accidentally delete a field.